# AngularJS using some controllers in 1 template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have diferents controllers in my app.

**admin.php:**

```
<body ng-controller="AdminController as AdminCtrl">
```

**player.php:**

```
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as interactCtrl">
```

these 2 .php documents have their respective **admin.js and player.js** with its .controller running correctly (I have more than these 2).

Now, I have the menu bar in menu.php, where I use in both **admin.php and player.php** documents, imported with:

```
<?php include('includes/menu.php'); ?>
```

So, if I want to use the values of each controller **(admin.js and player.js)** in the **menu.php**, how can I do it?

for example, I need to do this:

```
AdminCtrl.user.getUsername();
interactCtrl.user.getUsername();
```

But it is ridiculous because I would get js into an errors and if I had 500 controllers it wouldn't be recomended.

I thought that maybe I could do something similar to this:

```
<body ng-controller="AdminController as the_same_name">
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as the_same_name">
```

but I thint that all my controllers with the same name won't be a good idea.

What do you think?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly I recommend to store all the data you want to use cross-controller in one or more services, and then inject the service in your menubar controller. That way you can access the data you store in those services in your menubar.